# Image height: auto doesn't work on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I created a website with images that have a width of `160px`.
To avoid a distortion I don't set the height (or I add `height:auto;`).
Now the image height should be automaticly set (`90px` when the image is 16/9).

But when I open it with Chrome the image height is set to the original image height (`1080px`) while it still has a width of `160px`, therefore its very distorted

Do you know why it doesnt work with chrome? (Neither on Mobile nor on Desktop) And how can I make it work.

One solution would be to se the height manually to `90px`, but I want to set the width to `90%` of the parent which makes the width different on different screens. Therefore a set height doesn't make sense. But I also don't want to use JS

```html
Distortion on chrome but not on firefox
<div style="display:flex;">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hHzrRsf.jpg" style="width:160px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: Your container could be overriding the height:auto

Comment: The parent has `display:flex;` (What image can I use for code snippet?)

Comment: @LuisM. If the parent is flex, it's quite normal, and Chrome works pretty well. Please provide some code snippet or jsfiddle so that we can find a solution, but i'm already pretty sure it's some classic `align-self` or `align-items` problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```html
 <div style="display:flex;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hHzrRsf.jpg" style="width:160px;align-self: center;">
</div>
```

By default, `align-self` is set to `stretch` and remove the original height of your image.

Comment: This works fine. I am suprised because on firefox it works without `align-self: center;`

Comment: Nice :D This way, this will help the community when someone else will encounter the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/hHzrRsf.jpg" style="width:160px; height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

You can use Hight 100% that will be easy for you to understand

Comment: That doesn't solve the distortion, because the image gets the height of the parent container while the width stays fixed at 160px.